# I have my credit card ready, how do i increase the quota limits for an app script application

Tags: google-apps-script

I have written an entire application to do one and only one thing, notify the people on a shared folder in drive that a new file has been added to the folder.  the fact i had to write the application is baffling to me but whatever.

The person generating the content clicks on the notify button when he adds a new file, which on a good day would be about 2 or 3 hundred times, the system will go out, find the new files, get the list of people its shared with based on the folder, and generate an email for those people saying their file is ready to download via the link in the email.

my problem is he starts work about 8 in the morning and about 9 in the morning he gets a notification that he has hit the email quota for the day.

so, just to save time let me answer some of the mundane questions

1. he has a google apps for business account
2. no, he can not simply click the notify button less each day.  he typically works on
   a 5 to 15 minute turn around time for the files
3. in a given year he averages about 14,000 files added to the system with 200 clients
   and i would guess about 600 emails a day.
4. yes, i have rewritten the app several times now to minimize the number of times the api's are called.  I can't go any less than i am currently calling them because the toolset just isn't that good.
5. the server that ran this system previously was a P4 1 gig processor with 2 gigs of ram
   and a 500 gig hard drive that sits in his basement on the end of a
   128k ISDN line.  that server handled this task well for over 10
   years, i think google can handle the load
6. none of his clients have gmail accounts to be notified of new files as a shared folder

i have his credit card ready to upgrade the quota for the gmailapp api and the driveapp api inside the google app script language and i only need to know what screen to enter it to upgrade these quotas.

Am i going to have to rewrite this app yet again as a GAE app to make this work as expected?

thanks

Comment: It doesn't look like you can pay to increase your quotas. But I have an idea. For each folder, create a group for the people that have access to that folder. Or find some other way to have an idea of a "listserv" so that you're only sending 1 email per file uploaded. EDIT: Doesn't look like you can programmatically do this with Google Groups, so that might not be the best way to go. There's probably some service out there that will serve this purpose.

Comment: the frustrating thing is we had it narrowed down to a coin toss as to use google or write something using AWS.  if i could go back 6 weeks into the past, Google wouldn't have been on the table.  we just finished migrating his entire company to google.  everything.   he's going to freak if i come back and say its not going to work.

Comment: GAE may be the solution because that certainly has a page where you can pay to go beyond the free quota.

Comment: Instead of completely migrating over to AWS, try only using [Amazon SES (Simple Email Service)](http://aws.amazon.com/ses). There is a [HTTPS interface](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/query-interface-requests.html) for sending emails which you could probably invoke using [URLFetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_urlfetchapp). Edit: Just confirmed, it looks like you can add the necessary header (`X-Amzn-Authorization`) with URLFetch. That was the only thing that I wasn't sure about.

Comment: The [Dashboard](https://docs.google.com/macros/dashboard) for Google Apps Business accounts shows that the limit fo the number of Email recipients is 10,000 /day with a limit of 100 recipient/message, I'm surprised that you hit the limit when you mention an average count of 600 mails a day... How many recipient do you have for each mail ? 

I have an app in an Education account that sends mails to 800 people sometimes a few times in a day without hitting the limit

Comment: Can you please provide the from address and exact text of the message received in the notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an update, it turns out no-one is sure if these limits can be increased.  Therefor I rewrote the app in GAE.  At least with that framework and Drive API, if he ever hits any of the limits for the free account, he can be back up and running in minutes with a credit card, not have his entire business unceremoniously shut down for 24 hours with App Script.

Thank you all